# Strange windows border

Tags: release-juno, display

I'm using elementary OS 5.0 Juno. When I use right click of mouse to popup some menus, there will leave some strange window borders.I can reproduce this by using terminal and `smplayer`.
How to reproduce(with terminal):

1. Open `io.elementary.terminal` anywhere or any method.
2. Right click mouse popup menu, click 'copy' operation that will close right menu.
3. There will be a window frame border, seems window not refreshed outside the activated window.

How to reproduce:(with smplayer)

1. Open `smplayer`
2. left click mouse on the menu and do not select any operations, move mouse to next menu or prev menu, this action will close prev popup menu
3. There will be strange window borders

What's wrong with this？

[image: strange border with terminal]
[image: strange border]

Comment: Hello, I will try to reproduce the issue on my test machine. I will get back to you within tomorrow, sorry for the delay. Also let us know if there's been an update to the situation. Have a nice day!

Comment: Hi, I tried to update it to latest components of system, and switch to nvidia prime driver(nouveau before), the situation gets better. But sometimes there will be a border shadow/blur border not very clear. I think this does not bother me.

Comment: This issue comes back recently.

Comment: I see. My other computer is down right now. Let check this real quick on a VM. I will get back to you.

Comment: Again, sorry for replying late. I checked it on my test machine. Couldn't reproduce. Please update your system and let me know. Have a nice day!

Comment: Can you tell me on which kernel version of your test machine running and with which driver of video card, nouveau, intel or nvidia? I suspect the kernel version and video driver. Thanks.

Comment: I have reinstalled the whole system and updated to the newest, but the issue is persist.

Comment: If I disable animations through elementary-tweaks, the issue is gone.

Comment: I see, my kernel is 4.15.0-65-generic. My test machine is running a guest OS, and my host machine has AMD Radeon Graphics.

Comment: I'm sorry I tried several solutions, but these two method can get rid of it. One is installing older elementary os version loki, and the other one is replacing gala with compiz. I successfully replaced gala with compiz on Juno and enable animations working perfectly. It's solved for me anyway.  Thank you for your investigation finally whatever.